# Generate Unique ID in two places

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I need to generate a unique ID via js or PHP. Obviously this is pretty easy, but the part I can't figure out is that I need to generate a unique id for a `<p>` element, and then reference that unique id in some inline js below.

Here's the code to make this more clear:

```
<p id="UNIQUE-ID" class="toolbox"><a class="tooltip" onmouseover="tooltip.pop(this, '##UNIQUE-ID');"></a>
```

Basically, in both places where it says "UNIQUE-ID", I need an identical unique id generated. There will be an unknown number of these kind of `<p>` and `<a>` pairs generated dynamically.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Create <p> elements inside loop and make id like 'idname' concatenated with the loop variable i.

Answer (score 2):

You've said that the `<p>` and `<a>` pairs are generated dynamically, and also asked for a unique ID "...via js or PHP..." So I'm going to assume the dynamic generation is via PHP, in some kind of loop.

If so, just remember the value in a variable in your loop and output it in the two required locations, e.g.:

```
<?php
while (someCondition) {
    $id = /* ...generate the ID...*/;
?>
<p id="<?=$id?>" class="toolbox"><a class="tooltip" onmouseover="tooltip.pop(this, '##<?=$id?>');"></a>
<?php
}
?>
```

*(Obviously that's using shorttags, which many people recommend against. But it gets the idea across. If you don't use shorttags, you can easily change that to use `echo` instead.)*

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. Yes, it's via a PHP loop of sorts - this is within a WordPress template.

Comment: @Isaac: That should do it then. :-)

Comment: Extremely daft of me, WordPress has a built in variable for this purpose: %uid%

Comment: @Isaac: Well *that's* handy. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I am just giving the structure.Just change it according to your requirement

```
<?php
for($i=0;condition;$i++)
{
?>
<p id="par_<?php echo $i;?>" <a id="id_<?php echo $i;?>" href=""></a>
<?php
}
?>
```